# Parse a string in C to split the integers and the operators

Tags: c

So I recently started out learning C and it started to get a lot more complicated that I thought I would. I am having problems with my function to parse the string. What I am trying to do is parse the input for example: `50 + 50` or `50+50` so that it comes out as an array with `50`, `+`, `50` as different elements of the array. Here is the `parseString` function including its helper functions:

```
int testnumber = 0;

void test() {
    testnumber++;
    printf("Test %d", testnumber);
    printf("\n");
}

bool isNumber(char *token) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; token[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (!isdigit(token[i]))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool isOperator(char *token) {
    if (strlen(token) > 1)
        return false;
    switch (token[0]) {
      case '+':
      case '-':
      case '*':
      case '/':
      case '%':
        return true;
      default:
        return false;
    }
}

char **parseString(char *input) {
    test();
    int n_spaces = 0, i, start = 0, end;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++) {
        if (input[i] == ' ') {
            n_spaces++;
        }
    }
    char **tokens = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (n_spaces + 1));
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++) {
        if (input[i] == ' ') {
            end = i;
            tokens = realloc(tokens, sizeof(char*) * (n_spaces + 1));
            tokens[n_spaces] = malloc(end - start + 1);
            strncpy(tokens[n_spaces], input + start, end - start);
            tokens[n_spaces][end - start] = '\0';
            start = i + 1;
            n_spaces++;
        }
    }
    end = strlen(input);
    tokens[n_spaces] = malloc(end - start + 1);
    strncpy(tokens[n_spaces], input + start, end - start);
    tokens[n_spaces][end - start] = '\0';
    n_spaces++;
    int j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n_spaces; i++) {
        char *temp = tokens[i];
        if (isNumber(temp)) {
            tokens[j++] = temp;
        } else
        if (isOperator(temp)) {
            tokens[j++] = temp;
        }
    }
    
    test();
    tokens[j] = NULL;
    return tokens;
}
```

Here is also the main function that I use to test the output:

```
int main() {
    // Declare variable 'size' and initialize it with 100
    size_t size = 100;

    // Allocate memory for a character array and assign it to pointer 'input'
    char *input = malloc(size);

    // Read input from standard input and store it in the character array 'input'
    fgets(input, (int) size, stdin);

    char **tokens = parseString(input);

    test();
    int i;
    for (i = 0; *(tokens + i); i++) {
        printf("%s\n", *(tokens + i));
    }

    test();
    // Free up memory.
    free(input);
    free(tokens);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried adding a few `printf` in the `main` function to see why it doesn't give me the output I expected:

```
int main() {
    // Declare variable 'size' and initialize it with 100
    size_t size = 100;

    // Allocate memory for a character array and assign it to pointer 'input'
    char *input = malloc(size);

    // Read input from standard input and store it in the character array 'input'
    fgets(input, (int) size, stdin);

    char **tokens = parseString(input);

    printf("%s\n", tokens[0]);
    printf("%s\n", tokens[1]);
    printf("%s\n", tokens[2]);
    test();
    int i;
    /*for (i = 0; *(tokens + i); i++) {
        printf("%s\n", *(tokens + i));
    }*/

    test();
    // Free up memory.
    free(input);
    free(tokens);
    return 0;
}
```

But it just gives me the output:

```
Test 1
Test 2
50
+
(null)
Test 3
Test 4
Process finished with exit code 0
```

When I give it the input `50 + 50` but when I give it the input `50+50` it gives me the output:

```
Test 1
Test 2
(null)

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

Comment: Your `parseString` function counts the tokens by counting the number of spaces. That won't work with an input like `"50+50"`. What kind of resources do you have for learning parsing? What do they say about *lexing* or *tokenization*?

Comment: I will have to be honest i am not really using any resource i am just reading a bit of documentation here and there trying to piece it together. But i seem to understand what you mean. Would a better way be to use the helper functions to determine if it is a number or an operator?

Comment: @user3121023: deleting your answer seems unwarranted :)

Comment: First define "What is my allowable input?" You have started, but would `"5 5+"` also be allowed (or other variations?). If so, the loop method described by @Someprogrammerdude will work (generally called "walking down a string"). Essentially as described, you loop until you find a digit or operator. If operator read one character into your variable and set a flag, e.g. `haveop = 1;` Find the next digit and save the start location, index or pointer (note valid `int` can start with `+/-` so this is an additional chore for later).  Loop until not a digit and that's the end of that `int`. Repeat.

Answer (score 2):

This is a description on how I commonly handle parsing of tokens or lexemes.

What I usually do is to look at one or two characters at a time inside a loop, usually using a position variable (like an array index).

Initialize the current position to zero, to make the first character in the input string the "current character". Then enter an infinite loop. Inside the loop you check if it's the last character of the input, and if it is then return with an end-of-file or end-of-input value.

Then if the current character is a space (checked using `isspace`) then go to the next character in the input (increase the "current character" index by one) and `continue` the infinite loop.

After this I use a series of `if` statements to recognize the different tokens/lexemes. For example I could have

```
if (isdigit(input[current_position]))
{
    // TODO: Handle numbers
}
```

Similarly for other common tokens like strings and identifiers.

Each such check `return` with the correct values for the token.

Lastly for the "operator" tokens I use a `switch` statement to return their respective values:

```
switch (input[current_index])
{
case '+':
    return PLUS;
case '-':
    return MINUS;
// Etc...

default:
    // TODO: Error
}
```

If we haven't returned with a recognized token at this point it's an error, and I return with an error code or similar.

The infinite loop isn't really needed, but I think it makes handling spaces much easier. Also, I think it's easier to handle buffered input that needs to be read or fetched multiple times (if we reach the end of the current input, read new input, reset position/character indexes, and then `continue` the loop).

---

Now for the details of tokens like integers etc., when we have a digit as the current character then we fetch character by character and put into a new temporary buffer, as long as it's a valid character for the specific token. When we have a different character just stop the fetching, translate or convert the temporary buffer into the suitable type, and return.

The example with numbers could the be expanded to something like this:

```
if (isdigit(input[current_index]))
{
    char number_buffer[11] = { 0 }; // Enough for a 32-bit integer
    // Initialized to zero so there's a null-terminator at the end

    size_t number_position = 0;  // Position in the number-buffer

    // While there's a digit in the input, and we don't overflow the
    // number string buffer...
    while (isdigit(input[current_index]) && number_position < 10)
    {
        // Copy the character
        number_buffer[number_position++] = input[current_index++];
    }

    // TODO: Check for and handle if the number is too long

    // Now we can convert the number string into an actual value
    int value = strtol(number_buffer, NULL, 10);

    // TODO: Store the number somehow

    // Return to the caller, saying we found a number
    return NUMBER;
}
```

---

The method outlined above is rather generic, but the returns are geared more toward a parser instead of splitting up the tokens into an array.

But you can still use it as a base or a part of splitting the input into its separate tokens. Instead of returning the token type as in my examples above, you can store the characters into a buffer, terminate it, and return it (really pass the buffer as an argument to the function, and fill it).

Modification to fit your use-case are left as an exercise. :)